# How would one solve this equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Let's say I create a new operator, &, that works like so:

$x$&$n$ = $x^{x^{x^{...^{x}}}}$ ($n$ times)

So for example:

$3$&$2$ = $3^3 = 27$

$2$&$4$ = $2^{2^{2^{2}}} = 65536$

My question now is, how would I solve an equation like the following:

$x$&$2$ = $2$&$x$, where $x \in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: You did not define the operator $\&$ for real $n$.

Comment: You're describing something like $x \uparrow \uparrow n$, in Knuth's up-arrow notation.

Comment: The operator already exists (for natural numbers)

\begin{matrix}
   x\uparrow\uparrow k &  = & \underbrace{x^{x^{{}^{.\,^{.\,^{.\,^x}}}}}} 
\\  
    & & k\mbox{ times stacked }x
    \end{matrix}

Comment: It's called [tetration](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tetration)

Comment: Ive heard of that operator before, but I wasnt sure how it worked. Anyway, how would I solve the problem then?

Comment: Do you expect it to be between 0 and 1?

Answer (score 1):

As the operator is only defined for integers, the equation is

$$n^n=2\&n.$$

Then

$$1^1=1\leftrightarrow2\&1=2$$
$$\color{green}{2^2=4\leftrightarrow2\&2=2^2=4}$$
$$3^3=27\leftrightarrow2\&3=2^{2^2}=16$$
$$4^4=256\leftrightarrow2\&4=2^{2^{2^2}}=65536$$
$$5^5=3125\leftrightarrow2\&5=2^{2^{2^{2^2}}}=2.00352993\cdots10^{19728}$$
$$\vdots$$

Obviously, due to the fast growth, there is no other solution.

Comment: But could there be a negative number as a solution?

Comment: Hem, you also didn't define the operator for negative $n$.

Comment: If the operator were defined for all real numbers, how would all solutions be found?

Comment: @OawkemJenster: by using the definition, probably.

Comment: I got the idea for this problem from another problem, 2^x = x^2. In that problem, there are three solutions, and one of them, which is a negative number, can only be found using the Lambert W function.

Comment: @OawkemJenster: the Lambert function is defined for reals.

Comment: @OawkemJenster: you still haven't defined your operator.

Comment: The operator is defined for all real numbers.

Comment: @OawkemJenster: sure. What is $2\&1.5$ ?